# Customizing user module in zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am a zend frame work1 developer. I am trying to study zf2. But I came to know that zend1 and zend2 are entirely different. I am trying to build a simple application in which following features need to be implemented.

a) user registration and authentication

b) acl

I implemented zend skeleton.Now I am planning to implement user registration and authentication. For this I have 2 option

1) use already developed module like ZfcUser

2) develop new module for registration and authentication.

If I choose Ist method I have to study the whole concept of module ZfcUser for its customization. Which I felt difficulty in grasping the things like entity, mapper, service etc. So I am planning to go for my own auth and registration module.I am going to develop these as mentioned in Album module.

Can any one please help me to choose the right method?

Answer (score 0):

I completely disagree with the opinion of @Bilal

Don't develop Modules that have already been developed (and probably in a better way than you could do it). Use the existing Modules. Browse their respective source-code. Understand what they are doing. Understand why they are doing the things they do.

At some points in the future then you'll get to points where you want to modify little things that aren't always as easy as they should be and you'll be stuck with two options

- Modify existing Modules through a new Module
- Develop an entirely new Module with all your wanted features

But to say to write your own module just for the sake of learning, that's just completely wrong. You shouldn't blindly use existing stuff, you shouldn't blindly copy other stuff, but as long as you understand what you use or copy, there's absolutely nothing wrong in that. In fact it may actually be more beneficial because if you learn to understand other peoples code, you'll become a better programmer way faster than trying to teach everything yourself.